# What is the l4proto carp counter in nftables?

Tags: nftables

I was converting my iptables rules to nbtables and the script produced a few errors.

One of them was:
add rule ip6 mangle protos_check meta l4proto carp counter return
which was translated from
-A protos_check --protocol 112 --jump RETURN

Anyhow when I try to run nft this line produces and error.

Is there a specific module needed for this?

Comment: Welcome to SU. Vague problem descriptions like this aren't answerable. Please see the [guidelines for questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777478/edit) your question accordingly. Error analysis can't be done without the exact error messages, your NFT problems can't be analyzed without the NFT config and rulesets etc. Is the point of the question "how do I fix these errors" or "What is counter X in nftables?"

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Address_Redundancy_Protocol This?

Comment: It seems that `112` should be translated to `vrrp` instead though (or remain numeric as-is; should also work). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Router_Redundancy_Protocol

Comment: Btw `counter` is pretty much irrelevant to real question. It's just a generic tag that adds a counter to the rule for its matched traffics

Comment: Yeah I was wondering what carp was. I waas about to look at the source, god forbid.